# Wordpress function wp_get_attachment_image returns wrong size

Tags: wordpress, image, size, attachment

I'm using this code:

```
...
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">'. wp_get_attachment_image( $thumb_id, array(60, 60)). '</a>';
...
```

For some images I have correct output:

```
<img width="60" height="60" src="..." class="attachment-60x60 size-60x60" alt="..." srcset="..." sizes="(max-width: 60px) 100vw, 60px">
```

But for some it is bad:

```
<img width="1" height="1" src="..." class="attachment-60x60 size-60x60" alt="...">
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: You might try using `add_image_size()` and then calling that specific image size rather than an array of dimensions. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/.

Comment: As you can see in the documentation for `wp_get_attachment_image()` it is recommended to go the route suggested in my above comment. Read that here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/#description

Just keep in mind if your images are already uploaded you'll need to run an image resize tool after adding your new custom image size to regenerate the thumbnails of that particular size. This is a great plugin for doing that: https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue and it turned out to be a bug in the podPress plugin, so if you have that installed then try disabling it and see if it fixes it.